# How can I prevent parse currentUser from caching when sign up?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have my launcher activity, which starts the MainActivity IF the user hasn't *logged in* yet .However, when someone signs up, without logging in, and he restarts the app, it starts the MainActivity.
DispathActivity (which starts the correct activity):

```
    public class DispatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Parse.initialize(this, "g7ri9****F7yKTgKYRkJy8piZZD4JRab", 
"BzguaPll***************wSB9xDakiEMzFV");//I removed the keys, sorry hackers and trolls
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {
                // do stuff with the user
                Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                DispatchActivity.this.startActivity(startMainActivity);
            }
            else {
                // show the signup or login screen
                Intent startlogin = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                DispatchActivity.this.startActivity(startlogin);
            }
```

**Edit:** Sign up method:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(usernameString);
            user.setPassword(passwordString);
            user.setEmail(emailString);
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence success = "Sign up successful. An email has been sent to " + emailString + ", ple";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast successfullTostConformation = Toast.makeText(context, success, duration);
                        successfullTostConformation.show();

                        Intent startLogin = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(startLogin);
                    } else {
//                   There was an error signing up
                        switch (e.getCode()) {
                            case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN: {
//                   Username already taken
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already taken, try a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                            case ParseException.EMAIL_TAKEN: {
//                    email already taken
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email already taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                            case ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS: {
//                    bad email address
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                            case ParseException.EMAIL_NOT_FOUND: {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                            case ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED: {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an internet connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }
                            default: {
//                        Something else occured
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign up not successful, could be an internet or bad username/password problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

So, to make it more clear, when someone simply *signs up, * without *logging in*, I don't want MainActivity.java to start. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your signup code and callback functions? It'd be helpful to see how the response is being handled.

Comment: @Aaron , sure. Also, sorry for offtopic, but I've always wondered, how do you pronounce Aaron?

Comment: Success SignUp will login the user automatically. Why would you want to not log them in? Isn't it illogical?

Comment: @Ralphilius because I want them to verify their email.

Comment: Even that, I still can see it's common sense to keep login as seen in most of the web apps. In your case, you can use `ParseUser.logout()` or `ParseUser.logoutInBackground` in success SignUp callback.

Comment: Thanks. Although I don't need the answer anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question will be to:

> ## By @Ralphilius :
>
> you can use `ParseUser.logout()` or `ParseUser.logoutInBackground` in success SignUp callback.